# Calculate average session length per daily active user?

Tags: mysql, sql, average

[image]

I'm pretty new to SQL and I'm struggling with one of the questions on my exercise. How would I calculate average session length per daily active user? The table shown is just a sample of what the extended table is. Imagine loads more rows.

I simply used this query to calculate the daily active users:

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT user_id) 
FROM table1
```

Comment: You forgot to add the table :).  May want to come back and edit.

Comment: @JohnHumphreys-w00te Sorry, added it now!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also define what YOU mean by "average session length per daily active user".

Comment: *Hints:* 1) A SQL query described as "per" something implies a `GROUP BY` clause. --- 2) To "calculate average" you would use the `AVG()` aggregate function.--- Now make an attempt at writing the SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and welcome to StackOverflow!

now, your question:

> How would I calculate average session length per daily active user?

you already have the session time, and using [AVG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) function you will get a simple average for all

```sql
select AVG(session_length_seconds) avg from table_1
```

but you want per day... so you need to think as group by day, so how do you get the day? you have a `activity_date` as a Date entry, it's easy to extract day, month and year from it, for example

```sql
select
    DAY(activity_date) day,
    MONTH((activity_date) month,
    YEAR(activity_date) year
from
    table_1
```

will break down the date field in columns you can use...

now, back to your question, it states **daily active user**, but all you have is sessions, a user could have multiple sessions, so I have no idea, from the context you have shared, how you go about that, and make the avg for each session, makes no sense as data to retrieve, I'll just assume, and serves this answer just to get you started, that you want the **avg per day only**

knowing how to get the average, let's create a query that has it all together:

```sql
select 
    DAY(activity_date) day, 
    MONTH((activity_date) month, 
    YEAR(activity_date) year,
    AVG(session_length_seconds) avg 
from 
    table_1
group by
    DAY(activity_date), 
    MONTH((activity_date), 
    YEAR(activity_date)
```

will output the average of `session_length_seconds` per day/month/year

the `group by` part, you need to have as many fields you have in the `select` but that do not do any calculation, like `sum`, `count`, etc... in our case `avg` does calculation, so we don't want to group by that value, but we do want to group by the other 3 values, so we have a 3 columns with day, month and year. You can also use `concat` to join day, month and year into just one string if you prefer...